# positioning div below bootstrap positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, positioning

I have a site built with bootstrap. I'd like to add some purely design based blocks of color that cross over current rows and columns... the site layout is complex so I am thinking out of the box.  I would like to position a few divs independently of the bootstrap rows and columns grid but line up at some points/edges without messing up the flow/floats... Is there a javascript or css3 positioning solution I could use to have these few div's not affect the existing box flow at all? If I use absolute positioning I'm not sure that it will be sufficient to line up with current elements at some point. What id really like is another set of divs with bootstrap classes that don't affect the current flow and have a lower z-index... 
Weird question I know.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it is what your looking for bur take a look at css3 flexbox.

Comment: Thanks very much Darcey, flexbox looks interesting but it don't think it's quite what I want. I already have the bootstrap framework for the layout. 

What I'm envisioning is something like a javascript class that positions a div with bootstrap classes but has it not effect the positioning of other boxes.